# Vigilance is good for the soul - Frank Underwood

Tags: analysis, house-of-cards

In episode 6 of season 1 of House of Cards. Frank is caught in the teacher's strike crisis. And that night he stays awake in office with Doug Stamper. He appears tired. When Doug says "You should go home, I can take it from here'

Frank says

> "Vigilance, it's good for the soul."

Why does he say so ?
What does this mean in this context ?

I searched google and could not find any explanation on this. Could you please help ?

Answer (score 1):

> **vigilance**
>   ˈvɪdʒɪl(ə)ns/
>
> the action or state of keeping careful watch for possible danger or difficulties.
>       *e.g. security duties that demand long hours of vigilance*

In this context, Frank means "keeping watch on things".

*Why* it's good for the soul, he doesn't specify. My interpretation is either that's it's good because it means you retain control (instead of relying on others to not fuck up while you're not looking), or because it gives you peace of mind because you *know* the thing you're watching is safe (since you have your eyes on it).

E.g. keeping an eye on your child when it plays in the playground (vigilance) means you don't have to worry about what they might be doing (no worrying = good for the soul)